# Passing a form reference for accessing control in other class

Tags: vb.net

I have a form and one other class that basically maintains initialization state of the form (in this case, loading data from Json file to controls in form).

My form code:

```
Public Class PublishDigital
    Dim init As New InitForm(Me)
    Dim jhandler As New JsonHandler(Me)
    Dim jsonPath As String
    Dim jsonTxt As String

    Private Sub PublishDigital_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        jsonPath = Application.StartupPath + "\Addons\CG_Tools\cgSave.json"
        jsonTxt = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath)
        init.Setter()
        init.JenisOrder()
        init.FinishingA3()
        init.LayoutList()
        init.SisiMuka()
        init.Imposition()
        init.Folder()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And on initialization class, which calls a custom function to load JSON data to specified controls in main form (with prefix "cb"):

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Class InitForm
    Private frm As PublishDigital
    Public Sub New(ByVal parentform As PublishDigital)
        frm = parentform
    End Sub
    Public Sub Setter()
        'FillTabwithCB(ByVal frm As PublishDigital, cbdata As JArray, XOffset As Integer, YOffset As Integer, maxRow As Integer)
        JsonHandler.FillCBfromJson(frm.cb_operator, Globals.JsonObj("cgSetter"), "kode", "nama")
    End Sub
    Public Sub JenisOrder()
        JsonHandler.FillCBfromJson(frm.cb_jenisorder, Globals.JsonObj("cgJenisOrder")("katJenisOrder"), "id", "nama")
    End Sub
    Public Sub BahanUkuran()
        Dim parsedJenis = JsonHandler.ParseJsonToDictionary(Globals.JsonObj("cgJenisOrder")("dataJenisOrder"))
        JsonHandler.FillCBfromJson(frm.cb_bahan, parsedJenis(CType(frm.cb_jenisorder.SelectedValue, String)).Root, "kode", "bahan")
    End Sub
    Public Sub FinishingA3()
        JsonHandler.FillTabwithCB(frm, DirectCast(Globals.JsonObj("cgFinishing")("a3colorfn"), JArray), 7, 7, 5)
    End Sub
    Public Sub SisiMuka()
        JsonHandler.FillCBfromJson(frm.cb_sisimuka, Globals.JsonObj("cgLayout")("sisimuka"), "kode", "type")
    End Sub
    Public Sub LayoutList()
        Dim parsedJenis = JsonHandler.ParseJsonToDictionary(Globals.JsonObj("cgLayout"))
        JsonHandler.FillCBfromJson(frm.cb_layout, parsedJenis(CType(frm.cb_jenisorder.SelectedValue, String)).Root, "kode", "type")
    End Sub
    Public Sub Imposition()
        JsonHandler.FillCBfromJson(frm.cb_imposition, Globals.JsonObj("cgLayout")("imposition"), "kode", "type")
    End Sub
    Public Sub Folder()
        frm.cb_folder.Items.AddRange(Globals.TypeFolder.ToArray)
        frm.cb_folder.SelectedIndex = 0
        JsonHandler.FillCBfromJson(frm.cb_grouporder, Globals.JsonObj("cgPermanent")("kategori"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

These code works, but I feel like it could be improved somehow. Is this correct way to pass form controls to other classes?